# What of the knight of the Empty Helmet, and how does he comport himself at Castle Rhack?

Tags: jack-vance, lyonesse-trilogy

The epilogue of *Suldrun's Garden*, the first book of Jack Vance's Lyonesse series, is a sort of literary equivalent of a "next time" teaser in a TV series. More than summarising the events so far and describing the current state of affairs, it asks rhetorical questions about what will happen next. Many of these questions act as foreshadowing for significant events in later books:

- > Tamurello, fearing Murgen, refers Casmir to the wizard Shan Farway. In their plotting they use the name "Joald" and both fall silent.

  Foreshadows the Joald cataclysm at the end of book 3.
- > What of Glyneth, who loves Watershade and Miraldra, but yearns for her vagabond life with Dr. Fidelius? Who will woo and who will win her?

  Foreshadows Glyneth's otherworldly adventure at the end of book 2.
- > Aillas is King of South Ulfland and now he must reckon with the Ska, who wage war against the world. When he thinks of the Ska he thinks of Tatzel, who lives at Castle Sank. He knows a secret way into the fortress Poelitetz: how will this knowledge serve him?

  Foreshadows both the Tatzel escapade in book 2 and part of the war at the end of book 3.
- > Who nets the turbot who swallowed the green pearl? Who proudly wears the pearl in her locket and is impelled to curious excesses of conduct?

  Foreshadows the first chunk of book 2, about the green pearl.
- > And what of the knight of the Empty Helmet, and how does he comport himself at Castle Rhack?

  Wait, what the heck is this all about?

As far as I remember, having read all three books several times, neither the "knight of the Empty Helmet" nor "Castle Rhack" is *ever* mentioned anywhere else in the trilogy. But it seems beyond weird to introduce a character only for the sake of asking a teaser question about him which is never resolved or even mentioned before or since. Is this the most blatant violation of [Chekhov's Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun) I've ever seen, or is there some other mention of or reference to this person that I've missed?

In short: **I give up. *What* of the knight of the Empty Helmet, and how *does* he comport himself at Castle Rhack?**

Comment: Others have experiencend the same problem: http://jackvance.yuku.com/topic/2703/A-COUPLE-MISTAKES-IN-LYONESSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Christopher Priest's [obituary for Vance](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/may/30/jack-vance-dies-96-science-fiction) (2013) in *The Guardian*:

> Early in the 1980s Vance was diagnosed with glaucoma, but an attempted operation went wrong and afterwards he was declared legally blind. He continued to write with Norma's assistance, and later with the aid of special computer display software …

The loss of his sight must have made it difficult for Vance to consult the text of *Suldrun's Garden* (1983) when composing *The Green Pearl* (1985) and *Madouc* (1989), and it seems likely that the slips are a consequence of Vance having to rely on his fallible memory.

You'll see from the extracts that you quoted that it's not just the "Knight of the Empty Helmet" who fails to appear in the later books. "Shan Farway" too is absent; the fish that swallowed the green pearl changes from a "turbot" to a "flounder"; the person who "proudly wears the pearl ... and is impelled to curious excesses of conduct" is Red Flary (a man, not a woman). And there are many other minor inconsistencies, for example:

- How many people did the witch Desmei make in her vats? *SG*: Three. *GP*: Two.
- How long has Valdez been spying for Casmir? *SG*: Since before Aillas became king. *GP*: He can only have been doing so since Aillas became king, since Valdez is Yane, who was enslaved in Castle Sank until he escaped with Aillas.
- What was the origin of the placename ‘Twitten’s Corner’, where stands an iron post? *SG*: Twitten himself was compressed into a post and placed there by the magician Murgen. *GP*: The post was placed there by Twitten.
- Who made the prophecy about Suldrun’s son? *SG*: Desmei. *GP*: Persilian.
- Who appointed the devils Vus and Vuwas to guard Swer Smod? *SG*: Murgen’s enemies. *M*: Murgen.
- What is the name of the mad king of Pomperol? *SG*: Deuel. *GP*: Deul.

(I find the inconsistencies are one of the charming aspects of the series.)

Comment: (Wow, I'd almost given up hoping for an answer to this one!) Interesting. I never knew about Vance's blindness; presumably text-to-speech translation wasn't a thing back then? Re the Vus/Vuwas inconsistency - wasn't this resolved somewhere by saying that Murgen appointed them himself but let it be *thought* they were appointed by his enemies? And didn't Desmei always make 3 creatures in her vats, but one of them was quickly destroyed (this act leading indirectly to the green pearl, via Carfilhiot breathing in the fumes of its pyre)?

Comment: Anyway, yeah, lots of inconsistencies in minor detail. Another important one: Casmir learns in *SG* that Aillas was Suldrun's lover, and then learns it 'again' in *GP* or *M*. Vance is still a great violator of Chekhov's gun though :-) There was a passage in *GP* where Aillas and Tatzel see some weird creatures in a wood, which seems totally disconnected to anything else in the whole series. (Unless I've missed something - maybe this would be worth another question?) I guess the summary of this answer is that his Chekhov's Gun violations were due to his blindness and imperfect memory.