# What is the device Shimrod found with multiple balls moving together, and what does it signify?

Tags: jack-vance, lyonesse-trilogy

Towards the end of *Madouc*, book 3 of Jack Vance's *Lyonesse* series, Shimrod is studying a strange device with multiple (seven?) balls or discs moving around like planets. They move apparently asynchronously, but occasionally two and rarely three move together in unison. As he watches it, four, five, six, and finally all seven of the balls start moving in unison, until they appear to be all a single object. He goes to tell Murgen, but Murgen doesn't respond to his calls, and it is then that Shimrod discovers the plot to free Joald.

**What is this device, and what does it signify?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: It’s a model of the ‘superimposed worlds’ that indicates when it is possible to open a magic portal to the demon world ‘Xabiste’.

#### Magic portals to other worlds

It is established in the *Lyonesse* series that magicians can access other worlds or dimensions through magic portals. In *Suldrun’s Garden* Melancthe persuades Shimrod to visit ‘Irerly’:

> “In the forest nearby a door opens into the otherwhere Irerly. One of us must go through this door and bring back thirteen gems of different colours, while the other guards the access.”
>
> “That would seem to be dangerous work. At least for whomever enters Irerly.”
>
> […] Melancthe went to the door. She pulled at a heavy iron latch, drew it ajar, to display a wall of blank rock. […] From her cape Melancthe brought a curious hexagonal pattern, which she touched to the centre of the stone, where it clung. After a moment the stone dissolved to become luminous mist.

The nature of Irerly is otherworldly:

> In Irerly conditions were less easy than Shimrod had hoped. The sheath of sandestin-stuff lacked consistency and allowed sound and two other Irerlish sentiments, *toice* and *gliry*, to chafe against his flesh. […] Shimrod experienced a startling set of dislocations: a sound that reached him as a jet of ill-smelling liquid; other scents were red cones and yellow triangles […] Vision expressed itself as taut lines striking across space, dripping fire.

Similarly, in *The Green Pearl*, Visbhume tricks Glyneth into stepping through a door into ‘Tanjecterly’.

> She stepped from the hut, but where was the forest? She looked out on a strange landscape; where could she be? Two suns hung at the zenith of a heathergrey sky, lazily circling each other: one green, the other lemon-yellow. Short blue grass grew along a hillside sloping down to a slow gentle river, which flowed from right to left and out on a wide flat plain. Where the river met the horizon an object like a black moon hung in the sky, and the very look of the object caused Glyneth a spasm of unreasonable fear, even horror.

According to the ‘Pantological Index’, Tanjecterly is

> one of a set, or cycle, of ten superimposed worlds, which includes our own. Interconnections are difficult to find and evanescent in nature.

Confirming this description, Visbhume says that the portals between worlds can only be opened according to a complex schedule:

> “At a certain pulse, time is static both here and on Earth, and the gate can be opened at one node or another. See the black moon which moves around the northern sky? It strikes a radius with a central pole and somewhere along the radius a node can be opened, if pulses are in synchrony. It is a matter of exacting calculation, since time moves at different rates here and on Earth. Sometimes here time goes fast and on Earth slow, and sometimes the opposite. Only when time runs at the same rate, as determined by the pulses, can the gates be opened.”

#### The device

Murgen assigns Shimrod the task of:

> the analysis and classification of material confiscated from the wizard Tamurello […] Many [artifacts] showed no obvious utility, and Shimrod frequently puzzled as to their purpose or, conversely, their lack of purpose. For a month he had been studying such a contrivance: an assembly of seven disks of transparent material, rolling around the periphery of a circular tablet of black onyx. The disks swam with soft colours, and showed pulsing black spots of emptiness, forming and dying apparently at random. Shimrod could conceive no practical purpose for the device. A clock? A toy?

A device with multiple revolving disks suggests an [orrery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orrery) (a mechanical model of the solar system which can be used to predict the motions of the planets). Could this be something analogous?

> Shimrod found the disks a source of perplexity. They moved independently of each other, or so it seemed, so that in their circuit of the tablet, one might pass another, and in turn be overtaken by still a third. At times two disks rolled in tandem, so that one was superimposed upon the other, as if an attraction held them together for a few instants. Then they would break apart and each would once more roll its own course. At rare intervals, even a third disk might arrive while two disks rolled together, and for a space the third disk also would linger, for a period perceptibly longer than if just two disks were together. Shimrod once or twice had observed what would seem to be a very rare chance, when four disks chanced to roll together around the tablet, and then they clung together for perhaps twenty seconds before parting company. […] Was [it] a toy, or a complex curio, or **an analog representing some larger process**?

(My emphasis.) At the climax of the story:

> For a fact, five of the disks had joined to roll as one around the periphery of the tablet. Further, the disks showed no disposition to separate. And what was this? A sixth disk came rolling to overtake the five, and as Shimrod watched, it edged close, shuddered, merged into place with the others. Shimrod watched in fascination, certain that he was witnessing an important event or, more likely, the representation of such an event. And now the seventh and last disk came to join the others, and the seven rolled as one. The single disk changed in colour, to become marbled maroon and purple-black; it rolled lethargically, and showed no disposition to break apart. At the centre a black spot grew dense and large. Shimrod bent to look through the hole; he saw what appeared to be a landscape of black objects outlined in golden fire.

#### Xabiste

In *Madouc* we start to encounter references to ‘Xabiste’, which seems to be one of these other worlds. Early in the book, Murgen says:

> “Desmei in her creation of Melancthe and Carfilhiot used a demon magic derived from Xabiste. The green gas may itself be Desmei, in a form imposed upon her by the condition of Xabiste.”

At the climax of the story, the conjunction of the disks coincidences with the capture of Murgen by otherworldly arms:

> Murgen sat stiff and still in his chair, gripped by six long thin arms, putty-gray in color, sparsely overgrown with coarse black hairs. The arms terminated in enormous hands, two of which gripped Murgen’s ankles; two more pinioned his wrists; the final two covered his face, leaving only his two gray eyes visible. The arms extended from a slit or a notch opening into another space directly behind Murgen’s chair. The aperture admitted, along with the arms, a faint suffusion of green light.

which have emerged from ‘Xabiste’:

> Shimrod turned back to the table. The way into Xabiste was closing; to Shimrod's horror the arms, rather than disengaging, were drawing Murgen, chair and all, back through the slit.

Comment: Hmm. You've given evidence for two possible conclusions. 1) **The model symbolises portals to Xabiste specifically.** Obviously, circumstantial evidence is that the model portends the way to Xabiste opening. But then why are there *seven* different disks, if it only represents travel between two worlds? 2) **The disks symbolise different worlds.** The motion and conjunction of the disks seems very similar to the connections between those "superimposed" worlds. Ten worlds, seven disks, but that could be accounted for by [Vance's inconsistencies.](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/5611/17)

Comment: In my answer I didn't want to go beyond what can be demonstrated from the text, which leaves the details of the mechanism as a mystery.

Comment: Coming back to this, I'm accepting your answer because I think I was confused before. There does seem to be a clear connection to Xabiste specifically (there's nothing about other portals opening at the same time), so my idea of the discs symbolising different worlds doesn't make much sense - they might somehow symbolise different 'things' between our world and Xabiste, but not whole worlds like Xabiste, Tanjecterly, etc.